# What did I do wrong in the contract?

Tags: contract-development, wallets, ico

I don't know what the problem is there, if someone can help, I'll be so happy!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line you highlighted is a warning (you could add the view/constant keyword to it as it is not modifying any state variables)

If the code is not compiling it must be because some other error.